# having trouble in displaying text (with double quotes stored in a variable) to a modal through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I am having trouble in displaying text with double quotes through javascript. I want to display a text with double quotes in a modal. But in order to do this, I have to use javascript. The code is like this:
HTML code:

```
<button id="info" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoDetails" data-name="<?php echo $name;?>" data-detail="<?php echo $details;?>" >Click Here</button>
```

HTML code (inside modal):

```
 <p align="justify" id="detaiLInfo" style="font-size: 14px"> </p>
```

javascript code to display modal:

```
<script>
 $('#infoDetails').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { 
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var name = button.data('name') // Extract info from data-* attributes
    var details = button.data('detail')
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-header #name').text(name)
    modal.find('.modal-body #detaiLInfo').text(details)
});
```

Everything's working properly BUT when the value of `$details ="The term biology is derived from the Greek word βίος, bios, \"life\" and the suffix -λογία, -logia, \"study of.\"";`
It only gives this OUTPUT (inside the modal):

The term biology is derived from the Greek word βίος, bios,

But when I try to echo it inside html code (but not inside the code for modal) like this: `echo $details;` , the result is:

The term biology is derived from the Greek word βίος, bios, "life" and the suffix -λογία, -logia, "study of."

Can anyone help me to solve this? Please..

Comment: `<?php echo htmlentities($details);?>` ?

Comment: The problem is this " modal.find('.modal-body #detaiLInfo').text(details)" because when it read the first double quotes of the variable detail, it automatically escape. How can I solve this?

Comment: @AdrienXL Where will I echo it? Because it should be displayed inside the modal.. and the variable $detail is not inside the modal code..

Comment: In your button's data-detail attribute.

Comment: @AdrienXL, can you help me with this, please?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794299/image-resizing-without-uploading-it-again-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

If you examine what's happening, the HTML code generated by the server, as seen literally by the browser client, will get the `"` that opens "life" and be interpreted as the *closing* quote of the `data-detail` attribute, followed by trailing garbage which is then forgiven and ignored by the browser's HTML parser. I suggest using UTF-8 curly quotes in your explanatory text, side-stepping the issue and looking nicer! Otherwise, you could entity-encode the offending internal quotes. In general, packing long and/or *formatted* text into `data` fields is sort of a mis-use of the idea. Perhaps such data could instead be packed into the HTML content of a carefully `id`'d `display: none` storage area to be extracted dynamically with JS.

Scanning again it looks like a capp-o in `detaiLInfo`